# NG04002: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'analytics'

Tags: angular, angular-router

I'm using angular 17 without any modules(only standalone components)

I use the:

```
this.router.navigate([currentPage]);
```

command to change the components which are displayed in a router outlet
my routeConfig look like this

```
import {Routes} from '@angular/router';
import { SlideComponent } from './slides/slide/slide.component';
import { TaskComponent } from './slides/task/task.component';
import { AnalyticsComponent } from './slides/analytics/analytics.component';
import { SettingsComponent } from './slides/settings/settings.component';
import { OverviewComponent } from './slides/overview/overview.component';
import { LeaderboradComponent } from './slides/leaderborad/leaderborad.component';
const routeConfig: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'task',
    component: TaskComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'settings',
    component: SettingsComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'overview',
    component: OverviewComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'analytics',
    component: AnalyticsComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'leaderboard',
    component: LeaderboradComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'task',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: 'task',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];
export default routeConfig;
```

After Reloading my Webapp i get this error but only after reloading the webside

```
ERROR RuntimeError: NG04002: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'analytics'
```

I already tried to change the bootstrap like this:

```
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [provideProtractorTestingSupport(), provideRouter(routeConfig)],
}).catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

Comment: So you are saying that on the first load, analytics is fine, but on the reload, to that page, it fails?